# Redirect only urls with certain parameter to a new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect any page on a site that contains a p=item parameter at any point in the url to a specific url on a different domain.

I've tried to piece it together from various instruction on how to do it via htaccess but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=item(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ http://different-domain/url? [L,R]
```